# How to develop rails app for shopify with ScriptTags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, frontend, shopify

I have a shopify app deployed in Heroku, developed in Rails. 
I need call a javascript function from any shopify store's frontend.
I've read this article ( http://www.shopify.com/technology/3033852-shopify-api-update-scripttags-javascript-insertion ), but I don't understand it...

Where do I have to put this code:

```
HTTP POST http://their-shop.myshopify.com/admin/scripttags

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <script-tag>
    <src>http://example.com/your-awesome-script.js</src>
    <event>onload</event>
  </script-tag>
```

What should be the src tag (for my deployed rails app),
and where should I put the javascript call function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help.

[Shopify Rails App](http://wiki.shopify.com/Creating_an_app_and_deploying_it_to_Heroku_using_Rails_3)

You simply need to authenticate user and then you need to take the token generated from Shopify and save it in your Database. 
Later on just do:

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.site = token
```

and then install the script using:

```
s = ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:events => "onload",:src => "your javascript url")
```

and you are done!

Comment: Make sure that you set your source to "//your_javascript_url" if you need the JS to be executed on order success page.

Comment: Can you give me an example for "your javascript url"? I did it like this s = ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:events => "onload",:src => "//javascripts/shopify-try.js"), I put it to assets/javascripts/shopify-try.js (in rails directory), and I always get URI::BadURIError (both URI are relative) error. I tryed it like this: https://api.heroku.com/myapps/csiga-second-shopify/javascripts/shopify-try.js, but I get the same error.

Comment: The javascript url needs to be a public url that the js can be accessed from at runtime. For example: If you were trying to insert jQuery, your url might be `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: This is my code from controller:                                   sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params['shop'],response['credentials']['token'])
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:event => "onload",:src => "http://javascript.dataglobe.eu/index.js")  This is a public url, but I got this error: Failed.  Response code = 403.  Response message = Forbidden. Why is it forbidden?

Comment: Oh, I found the answer... that was because of the lack of write_script_tags scope....

Comment: Don't forget it should be :src =>

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to get it working:

In the sessions_controller.rb file located in app > controllers

After this

```
def show
  if response = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params[:shop], response[:credentials][:token])
    session[:shopify] = sess
```

I added

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:event => "onload", :src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js")
```

You need to replace `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js` in the code above with your absolute js file path.

Then in the omniauth.rb file located in config > initializers
make sure you add `write_script_tags` to the scope i.e.

```
:scope => 'write_script_tags',
```

and you might also need to restart your rails server and re-install the app so that these privileges have been granted. That should do the trick!